# Replacing dir.h for C API file management

Tags: c, visual-studio, file-io

I am updating a 16-bit program written as a C program and originally compiled with a Borland C compiler. It will be compiled with Visual Studio as a 64-bit CLI app for Windows 7 and the hope is to minimize the coding changes. The 16-bit file management calls are no longer available. Basically, the functionality that was originally prototyped in dir.h is not available. What is the simplest way of replacing functionality for the following dir.h functions:
_setdisk()
_getdisk()
_getcurdir()
_searchpath()

Hoping to get advice as my experience with C APIs is limited?

Comment: Substitutes in `<direct.h>` are _chdrive(), _getdrive() and _getcwd().  `<stdlib.h>` has _searchenv().

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Borland docs](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/borland_C++/Borland_C++_Version_4.0_Library_Reference_Sep93.pdf) as a spec to help you implement your own versions in terms of win32 API calls. Some of them look like they will map easily, for example:

- [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Others look like they may be more work:

- [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

One thing to consider if you have such an old application: depending on its size it may be better to rewrite it rather than to port it. You may find that C++ or C# provide libraries to allow you to achieve the same result with less code in a way that will allow you to more easily make enhancements.

Comment: For example: boost filesystem: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm